# Hydrogen peroxide to clean water heater

Tags: water-heater

As I pour in the peroxide, in a few moments it bubbles back out, even doing just an ounce at a time, I removed 6 gallons of water before starting.  Why is it coming back out of the heater?

Comment: Yes that is what they recommend.  It kills the bacteria, does not hurt the plumbing, bleach is okay but corrosive so not as good a choice.  This is when only your hot water gets sulfur smell.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik -- see [here](http://www.waterheaterrescue.com/Troubleshooting/stinky-water-in-hot-water-heaters.html) for details

Comment: What port are you pouring the hydrogen peroxide into?

Answer (score 0):

There is a drain valve at the bottom of the water heater. It is used to flush accumulated silt from the bottom of the tank, and that alone may help remove some of the sulfur smell. Draining some water also will leave room for some hydrogen peroxide.

**N.B.: Drain valves may be difficult to shut after opening... If not used for years, parts may need to be replaced to get the drain to stop dripping.**

- Shut the electricity or gas from the heater.
- While the tank is connected to the cold water line, connect a garden hose to the drain valve and put the other end in a **large** bucket, sink drain or outside.
- Open the drain valve for ten or fifteen seconds to clean out sediment.
- Close the valve between the cold water source and the water heater.
- Open hot water taps at each faucet to allow the system to drain out the hose.
- *After the water level has dropped below the top of the tank*, close the drain valve.
- Add hydrogen peroxide as in the [directions](http://www.waterheaterrescue.com/Troubleshooting/stinky-water-in-hot-water-heaters.html) from @ThreePhaseEel.
- Close up the system.
- Turn on the cold water valve to the heater, and let the air in the hot water pipes hiss out until water comes out, then close the faucets.
- Turn electricity or gas on again and, if gas, light the pilot light.

[image: Two types of drain valves, from http://clearwaterplumber.com/maintaining-water-heater and http://www.doityourself.com/forum/water-heaters/512423-hot-water-tank-drain-valve-help.html]

Comment: Missed the "shut off the heater" step. Great way to burn out the top element on an electric heater, for instance, or both if you drain enough, or burn out a gas heater if you drain enough.